# Inno Script Generator - Unable to Create Registry Entries

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I am running InnoScriptGenerator 1.0.3.1 to create an install script.
Everything works EXCEPT the registry creation.  I want to create two entries...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DocAssist
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DocAssist\InstallDir   - which has my install directory
```

My script lines are as follows:

[Registry]

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\DocAssist; ValueType: none; Permissions: admins-full; Flags: uninsdeletekey createvalueifdoesntexist;
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\DocAssist; ValueType: string; ValueName: InstallDir; ValueData: {app}; Permissions: admins-full; Flags: uninsdeletekey createvalueifdoesntexist
```

The script runs, does not give an error, but also does not create the entry in the registry.

When I run it from InnoScript Generator, the debug log shows

[image: Screen Install Log]

I am running this as an admin user.  It is being run on Windows 7 64 bit.
The only other interesting piece of info is that in my application, when it accesses the registry, (via Delphi) I had to define the Registry as...

```
MyRegistry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
```

because

```
MyRegistry := TRegistry.Create();
```

just did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inno (unless you've told it otherwise) will be writing that value into the 32bit view of the registry.
You've then told your app (using the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag) to read formt he 64bit view.

As it sounds like your app is actually a 32-bit app, just use HKLM exclusivly, and forget any 64 bit flags.
This will cause the value to be correctly written into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DocAssist` in the 32bit view (which is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\DocAssist` in the 64bit view.)

See the [various](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [articles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459) on the Microsoft websites for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the registry section like this just works fine:

```
[registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\DocAssist; ValueType: none; Flags: uninsdeletekey       createvalueifdoesntexist;
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\DocAssist; ValueType: string; ValueName: InstallDir;     ValueData: {app}; Permissions: admins-full; Flags: uninsdeletekey createvalueifdoesntexist
```

You cannot set the persmission on a non existing key. You might also consider on using HKCU rather than HKLM because you won't have any admin rights problems. This is the right way to use the registry since Vista and UAC.

Comment: Re HKCU vs HKLM. It's the contrary, the setup CAN NOT reliable write to any particular HKCU and the one for the setup may be very different to the one for the user themselves. Global data like this should go into HKLM.